# how to add Jlabel into Jtable column?

Tags: swing, runtime, jtable, jlabel

I want to add two Jlable(edit or delete) into perticular column of Jtable at runtime.
i dont' know how to do that.
please provide me some reference or code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: typically, you _do not_ add components to the model, instead use a custom renderer to render the data as appropriate. So what exactly are to trying to achieve?

Comment: You might want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html for more information on cell renderers